# String problems with Javascript double quotes inside single

Tags: javascript, string

This is my code:

```
<script>
    function popupTest(title) {
        alert(title);
        return false;
    }
</script>

<a href="" onclick="return popupTest('This is &#039;some&#039; &quot;test&quot; string')"><span>Recommend</span></a>
```

Using Firefox 4 I get the error:

```
Error: missing ) after argument list
Source Code:
return popupTest('This is 'some' "test" string')
```

It's like it's decoding the HTML entities but I don't know why.

Have also tried...

```
<a href="" onclick="return popupTest('This is \'some\' \"test\" string')"><span>Recommend</span></a>
```

Which gives error:

```
Error: unterminated string literal
Source Code:
return popupTest('This is \'some\' \
```

Comment: While the answers here are correct, the proper solution would be giving the element an ID and then attaching an event handler to it using JavaScript instead of inlining an `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`&#039;` is **HTML** for `'`. So for the first example the HTML is parsed and the JavaScript engine is passed:

```
return popupTest('This is 'some' "test" string')
```

… and the second `'` terminates the string.

On the other hand:

```
onclick="return popupTest('This is \'some\' \"test\" string')"
```

Is parsed as:

> An onclick attribute with the value `return popupTest('This is \'some\' \` followed by some invalid data.

You need to deal with the JavaScript first:

```
return popupTest('This is \'some\' "test" string')
```

**and** then escape it for HTML:

```
onclick="return popupTest('This is \'some\' &quot;test&quot; string')"
```

You would probably be better off using [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and binding the event handlers with JavaScript instead of using intrinsic event attributes.